# jquery modification required to skip code execution

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins

I am using this lovely jquery plugin

http://www.gayadesign.com/diy/queryloader2-preload-your-images-with-ease/

It loads your whole website including images before displaying it. It works perfectly well. What I wanted to do was add a small skip button which would skip the script and jump to the page without preloading for people who are too impatient.

```
//create the skip button
this.skipbutton = $("<div id='skip'><a href='#' id='skipbut'>SKIP</a></div>").css({
    height: 20 + "px",
    marginTop: "-" + (this.parent.options.barHeight / 2) + "px",
    Color: this.parent.options.barColor,
    width: "0%",
    position: "absolute",
    top: "70%",
    left: "50%"
}).appendTo(this.container);
```

I wanted to now know how to skip it ..I didnt think stop() function would work for this?

```
//skip function
$("#skipbut").click(function(){
        //insert code here
});
```

SO Any help in the right direction would be highly appreciated. Thank you so much in advance :-)

Comment: if you're binding the skipbut click before the creation of the button it won't work

Comment: no I have put the skipbut click function right at the end

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a very simple solution, though I will confess its not the ideal one but I had to move quickly

I made another clone of the page without the preloader and attached a redirect action to the skip button.

SO technically it loaded a clone of the page without the preloader. Works fine but not the way I would have wanted it too.

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution is you can set local storage for that and reload your page:

```
$("body").on('click','#skipbut',function(){       
     localStorage.setItem("load","true");
     location.reload();
});
```

And check it when you are loading your plugin , something like this :

```
$(document).ready(function () {
     if( localStorage.getItem("load")=="true" ){             
         // if local storage is set skip the loader 
         localStorage.removeItem("load");
     }else{
         // if localstorage is not present use the loader
         $("body").queryLoader2();
     }
});
```

Hope it shed some light.

Comment: Hi Mr Tyagi, Thanks but it didnt work. Skip button still pretty dead :) . DO you think its possible that the skip button i created is not detecting the click function ? though I have given it a proper ID and #in front $("#skipbut").click(function(){

Comment: Ahh I see what you did there but it still did not work :( so I guess its not a problem with the detection of the click.

Comment: Hi , it worked partially. I was making a mistake . I wasnt putting the button function within the document.ready ..so it wasnt working. Now the button is working but all it does is restart the loader from beginning . Any ideas?

Comment: Yes this is what it does it restart the page and skip the loader this  time as local storage is present. ( provide your code where you are using the plugin )

Comment: i am sorry I didnt understand you, did you ask for the html code? or the jquery plugin code?

Comment: where did you use your plugin in your code like I use ' $("body").queryLoader2();'